# useState not working for array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am making a small weather app using React. I intend to use the `useState` hook for an array of objects. Through an array of objects - `latLongStore`, I make multiple axios `get` calls to fetch weather data for different cities. The fetch part works well but `weatherData` values do not show up in the DOM. It has the correct number of objects but appears to contain no values. Below is my code:

```
...
const latLongStore = [
  { latitude: 23.8315, longitude: 91.2868, title: "Agartala", color: "#299617", code: 'VEAT' },
  { latitude: 23.0225, longitude: 72.5714, title: "Ahmedabad", color: "#299617", code: 'VCBI' },
...
]

const initialData = {
    city: '',
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
    max_temperature: 0,
    min_temperature: 0
}

function TableView(props) {
    const [weatherData, updateWeatherData] = useState([initialData]);

    useEffect(() => {
        
            latLongStore.forEach((latLong) => {
                axios.get(`api-url`).then((response) => {

                    const fetchedData = {
                        city: latLong.title,
                        latitude: response.data.latitude,
                        longitude: response.data.longitude,
                        max_temperature: response.data.daily.temperature_2m_max[0],
                        min_temperature: response.data.daily.temperature_2m_min[0]
                    }

                    console.log(fetchedData);

                    updateWeatherData(weatherData => [...weatherData, fetchedData]);
                })
            })
    }, []);

    switch (weatherData.length) {
        default:
            return (
                <div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    LOADING...
                    {weatherData.length}
                </div>
            )
        // weatherData contains 62 objects after fetch but no values show up in DOM
        case 62:
            return (
                <div>
                   <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    { weatherData.forEach((data) => {
                        <div>
                            { data.city } : { data.latitude }, { data.longitude }
                        </div>
                    }) }
                </div>
            )
        // default:
        //     return (
        //         <div>
        //             <br />
        //             <br />
        //             <br />
        //             <br />
        //             LOADING...
        //         </div>
        //     )
    }

}

export default TableView;
```

Here's the output:

- At a particular instant of updation

[image]

- After the `weatherData.length` reaches 62
  [image]

Can someone tell me how I can show up `weatherData` values in DOM.

Comment: `weatherData.forEach` will return `undefined`, use `weatherData.map` instead. Additionally, it would be wiser to initialise weatherData as an empty Array: `const [weatherData, updateWeatherData] = useState([]);`

Comment: It still does not work. No values show up in the DOM

Comment: you should use  **weatherData.map** insetad of  weatherData.forEach added to that are you sure about 62 ? make a console.log maybe it can be 63 based on the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Your `forEach` function is actually doing nothing there. It's just looping through an array and that's all. You need to use `Array.map()` and make the callback function return something. Like this (not tested):

```
{
  weatherData.map((data) => {
    return (<div>
      {data.city} : {data.latitude}, {data.longitude}
    </div>)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: I've removed the API request in the snippet as otherwise the snippet wouldn't work. (You can obviously put that back inside the `useEffect`)

I would recommend you **don't** depend on the length of the resultant array. But rather focus on if the request(s) are loading or not.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const latLongStore = [{
    latitude: 23.8315,
    longitude: 91.2868,
    title: "Agartala",
    color: "#299617",
    code: 'VEAT'
  },
  {
    latitude: 23.0225,
    longitude: 72.5714,
    title: "Ahmedabad",
    color: "#299617",
    code: 'VCBI'
  }
]

// const initialData = {
//     city: '',
//     latitude: 0,
//     longitude: 0,
//     max_temperature: 0,
//     min_temperature: 0
// }

function TableView(props) {
  const [weatherData, updateWeatherData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    // Set Loading to true before requests
    setIsLoading(true);
    latLongStore.forEach((latLong) => {
      // I have removed the request as I can't access whatever API being used
      const fetchedData = {
        city: latLong.title,
        latitude: latLong.latitude,
        longitude: latLong.longitude,
        max_temperature: 5,
        min_temperature: 2
      };

      // console.log(fetchedData);

      updateWeatherData(weatherData => ([
        ...weatherData,
        fetchedData
      ]));
    })
    // Set Loading to false after
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div >
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        LOADING...{weatherData.length}
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      {weatherData.map((data, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          {data.city}, {data.latitude}, {data.longitude}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )

}


ReactDOM.render(
  <TableView /> ,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```